# Grouping \usepackage in a single entity

Tags: packages

I want to group several calls to `\usepackage` in a styles file.  Where users can select an option that automatically adds the packages to their document.

Grouping the following under single name

```
mathabx MnSymbol fdsymbol boisik stix mathdesign
```

Grouping these under single name

```
stmaryrd wasysym turnstile trsym trfsigns cmll colonequals fourier
```

Comment: what do you mean by group here, one option that just loads one paackage from a group? Your groupings seem weird, you could only load one from the first group,  but could load any of the second

Comment: Apart from the fact that loading together all packages in the first group will have, at the least, funny consequences, what makes you think that some user would like to load all packages in the second group? By the way, adding also `fourier` to the packages in the first list will have even funnier consequences. Leave package loading to the user, unless a package is strictly necessary for your own package.

Comment: yes I hadn't noticed fourier in the second group:-) so neither group is usable as a group

Comment: I have not gone into the details of the packages.  But want to make it easy for user to use mathematics related packages for instance.  Because the normal build-in symbols do not provide all that is necessary for writing mathematics document.  I continually have to look for the package name for a particular symbol when not provided by the default built-in ones.

Comment: @konmi It's general knowledge that using, for instance, `MnSymbol` just because it has a symbol that's lacking in the default setting is not a good idea, for it changes *all* symbols in a way that's usually incompatible with the document fonts.

Comment: So why are these things documented and promoted?  This just confuses users.

Comment: @konmi: Take MnSymbol for example, its'd documentation [clearly states](https://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol?lang=en) "MnSymbol is a symbol font family, designed to be used in conjunction with Adobe Minion Pro (via the MinionPro package)." If you are using a font that doesn't look like Minion Pro, there's a good reason to expect that MnSymbol won't work well with your font. // You may find [this article](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf) enlightening. Note that the article is somewhat dated and does not include newer fonts like STIX or kpfonts.

Comment: That means that I would have to make some tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to focus on answering the general form of the question, i.e., how to declare an option that would load multiple packages.

There may be other ways, but I'd probably have the options set the value of a boolean variable, and then use that variable with a conditional, and load the packages only if the variable is set to true.

This will give you the rough idea:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2022/10/03 an example package]

% declare a boolean for "foo", default off
\newif\iffoo
\foofalse
% declare a boolean for "bar", default off
\newif\ifbar
\barfalse

% the options set the booleans to true
\DeclareOption{foo}{\footrue}
\DeclareOption{bar}{\bartrue}

% process the options before checking if the booleans are true
\ProcessOptions

% load several packages if foo is chosen
\iffoo
    \RequirePackage{package1}
    \RequirePackage{package2}
    \RequirePackage{package3}
    \RequirePackage{package4}
\fi

% load several packages if bar is chosen
\ifbar
    \RequirePackage{package5}
    \RequirePackage{package6}
    \RequirePackage{package7}
    \RequirePackage{package8}
\fi
```

Used in the document with `\usepackage[foo]{mypackage}`, etc.

This will not work as is with the particular sets of packages you specified, because they conflict with each other, as discussed in the comments. I doubt there's a way to use all of them at once, and I'm not sure why you'd want to. That's a separate issue, however.

Comment: Perhaps an idea is to have an extended and quite complete categorisation package for certain tasks without having conflicts.

Comment: An `Undefined control sequence` is fired for `\foofalse`.

Comment: I can't replicate that, and I cannot see how it could possibly be true unless you changed something important. Post your actual code that generates that result.

Comment: Got it to work now.

Comment: Using `\newtoggle` seems more readable.  Perhaps pass `\toggletrue{foo}`.

Comment: If you're loading etoolbox anyway that makes sense. If you're not, I'd try to keep the dependencies of any package to a minimum.